# Dygrahs js (ticker): different thickness and color of the line (x-scale)

Tags: javascript, css, dygraphs, ticker

I want to change one of the vertical lines of the grid (different thickness and color of the line) - set the rule by which the line style will be set.

I'm trying to combine such tools: ticker and axisLabelFormatter;
My goal: to make a grid on the X axis every 15 seconds, but the line multiple of 30 seconds should be thick (or raise width: gridLineWidth).

My code is here:
`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/cLw2grga/

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this effect using a ticker, but you can using an [`underlayCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#underlayCallback):

```
underlayCallback: function(ctx, area) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  for (var x = 15000; x <= 300000; x += 30000) {
    var domX = this.toDomXCoord(x);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(domX, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(domX, area.h);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.restore();
}
```

See [full example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLw2grga/1/).

Comment: This solution does not work with the Range Selector.
These lines are static, so when I move the range selector, the lines on the X scale do not go along with the plot

Comment: That is not correct. Here's a version of that fiddle with range selector: https://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/10566/ (I also updated to dygraphs 2.)